# error on private inheritance and function overloading

Tags: c++

I have a problem which I narrowed down to the following code:

```
class A
{
};

class B : private A
{
};

void f(A*)
{
}

void f(void*)
{
}

int main()
{
  B b;
  f(&b);
}
```

Which gives the following error with gcc 4.7:

```
error: ‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’
```

I know that A is inaccessible but I would have liked the compiler to call f(void*). Is this behavior normal or am I doing something wrong? Or maybe it's a compiler bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloading is resolved **before** access checking. So the compiler chooses `f(A*)` as the appropriate overload, then determines that `&b` can't be converted to `A*` and gives the error message.

Comment: As for the reason why this is so: *because* it causes such error. So if you want to prevent people from calling `f(void*)` accidentally, you now know how, and if they still do want to call it, they can just cast `f(static_cast<void*>(&b));`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, though I'm a bit disappointed by it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `b` is being passed in as a `void *`, which won't be the default case since `b` is actually an instance of `A`. Just explicitly tell `f()` that `b` is `void *` by casting it:

```
class A {
};

class B : private A {
};

void f(A*) {
}

void f(void*) {
}

int main() {
  B b;
  f((void*)&b);
}
```

Comment: This would indeed solve the problem, but in my case, I don't have access to the f call, I can only change the class A and B.